# use standard datastore index or build my own

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I am running a webapp on google appengine with python and my app lets users post topics and respond to them and the website is basically a collection of these posts categorized onto different pages.

Now I only have around 200 posts and 30 visitors a day right now but that is already taking up nearly 20% of my reads and 10% of my writes with the datastore.  I am wondering if it is more efficient to use the google app engine's built in get_by_id() function to retrieve posts by their IDs or if it is better to build my own.  For some of the queries I will simply have to use GQL or the built in query language because they are retrieved on more than just and ID but I wanted to see which was better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing efficient caching? (or any caching at all).

Also, if you're using that many writes for 300 posts, seems like you might have a problem with your models. Have you looked at the Datastore viewer to seem how many writes you use per entity?

You might read the docs on [Exploding indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes), maybe that's part of your problem?

It's way better to use `get_by_id()`. It finds the exact object, and costs way less (counts as a query with only one entity).

Comment: no I am not doing caching, I'm just about to learn that and fix up the site it.  I suppose I have 20 writes per entity because I have 9 properties and then the 1 for the index and 1 for the entity.  Is that a lot? I don't  really know how to reduce that with what I have

Comment: @exployre if some of them don't need to be indexed (you don't need to do a *datastore* search by them), you can add `indexed=False` to the class definition for that entity, e.g. `some_property = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)`, which would let you have a string property "some_property", that is stored on the entity but is not indexed (so you can't search for it). This (should) reduce the number of writes.  Definitely worth testing out.

Comment: @exployre also, as above, you should use `get_by_id`, it's much cheaper and faster

Comment: alrighty, I just got caching down and now I am trying to rework it to use get_by_id() for a few areas, though it isn't really possible in some

Comment: just one final quick question.  I am retreiving the posts by their id which I get from the URL where they are hosted.  should I store the comment ID as a property of the post and then retreive the comments in this way?

Comment: why not just use the url as the key name (you can use ids or names as key names)? You just have to be careful: the Datastore will overwrite any keys that already exist (and, in fact, it doesn't differentiate between saving a new entry and saving a modified entry). You should go check out the docs for more.

Comment: yeah that's actually what I'm doing right now and it seems to be working quite well

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using pre-existing code and building around that in stead of re-inventing the wheel.